# Will The Flea Catch The Kangaroo

Tags: sequences-and-series

On a mock exam paper I saw this question. Can't seem to find an answer anywhere:

"There is a kangaroo attached to a pole by an infinitely extensible string such that the distance between the kangaroo and the pole is zero. This Kangaroo then jumps 1km away from the pole. A flea that was standing on the pole then jumps along the string a total length of 1cm. The Kangaroo then jumps 1km again and the flea then jumps another cm. This series of moves continues infinitely. Will the flea ever catch the Kangaroo?
Assuming the earth is flat and stretches infinitely in all directions."

Comment: You've tagged this as sequences and series, which definitely is a hint to the approach. What sequences and series have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

After the the first jump of the flea, the total ratio of the rope *behind* the flea and in front of her is $\frac{1}{100,000}$

Before the second jump, the ratio remains the same. After the jump, however, the ratio is $$\frac{1}{100,000} + \frac{1}{200,000}$$

and after $n$ jumps, it's $$\frac{1}{100,000} + \frac{1}{200,000} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n\cdot 100,000}$$

Comment: Wouldn't the ratio be $\Large \frac{1}{k\cdot 100.000}$ after $k$ jumps since the string is extensible?

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake The string extends with the flea on it. So, in each jump, the flea **adds** another $\frac{1}{k\cdot 100,000}$ to the ratio (basically, the kangaroo is also pulling the flea). After the first jump, the flea jumped 1cm and the cangaroo then goes another kilometer, pulling the flea to $2$ centimeters, then the flea jumps another centimeter to $3$ centimeters. The added centimeter is the $\frac{1}{2\cdot100,000}$.

Comment: I feel stupid now but thanks for this, it helped "visualize" the answer and make it much clearer for me. +1

Comment: These are actually the ratios of the length of rope behind the flea to the total length of the rope, not of the lengths behind and in front of the flea. (Otherwise, the divergence of the ratio wouldn't show that the flea eventually catches the kangaroo.)

Answer (score 0):

As $5$xum’s answer shows, the flea catches the kangaroo because the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges.

Interestingly, even though the number of jumps required is beyond astronomical, we can determine it precisely. The flea catches the kangaroo once $H_n\ge10^5$, where $H_n$ is the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which is asymptotically approximated by

$$H_n=\log n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\;,$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). Solving for the argument of the logarithm yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
n
&=&
\exp\left(H_n-\gamma-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)\exp\left(-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)\left(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)-\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)\left(\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)-\frac n{1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}\left(\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)-\frac12+O\left(\frac1n\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $n$ is huge, the error term is tiny, so we have

$$
n\approx\exp\left(H_n-\gamma\right)-\frac12
$$

to within a tiny fraction of a jump. Thus the flea catches the kangaroo after

$$
\exp\left(10^5-\gamma\right)-\frac12
\approx
1.6\cdot10^{43429}
$$

jumps.